# 403 during user creation using keycloak-admin-client

Tags: java, keycloak

I am trying to create a new user with java-admin-client. I created a new client in my realm using keycloak UI.

Client:

access type: confidential

roles: view-users, view-realm, view-clients, manage-users (these roles are just added by name in keycloak UI)

Code:

```
final Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
    .serverUrl("https://{keycloakurl}/auth")
    .realm(realm)
    .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
    .clientId("client")
    .clientSecret("uuidSecret")
    .build();

final UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
user.setEnabled(true);
user.setUsername("test");
user.setFirstName("test1");
user.setLastName("test2");
user.setEmail("test@test.com");
user.setAttributes(Collections.singletonMap("origin", Arrays.asList("demo")));

final RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm(realm);
final UsersResource userResource = realmResource.users();

final Response response = userResource.create(user);
```

The last line is giving me 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Did you check Keycloak logs why you are getting 403? Maybe you need higher/different role.

Comment: My logs are not logging this action at all. But maybe I need to enable different logging level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 403 as you have no role 'manage-users'. Add to your user fro 'realm-management' client, inside your realm.

We created one service-account user, just to query users by uuid. These three files does that, plus properties from application.properties. Update code and try what you wanted

```
@EnableOAuth2Client
@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfiguration {

//  token-service-uri=https://keycloak.internal/auth/realms/some-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
//  admin-query.client-id=client
//  admin-query.username=service-account
//  admin-query.password=password
//  admin-query.admin-base-url=https://keycloak.internal/auth/admin/realms/realm

@Value("${token-service-uri}")
private String tokenServiceUri;

@Value("${admin-query.client-id}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${keycloak.credentials.secret}")
private String clientSecret;

@Value("${admin-query.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${admin-query.password}")
private String password;


private final String grantType = "password";


@Bean
public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails cryptoKeycloakResourceDetails() {

    ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails details = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
    details.setAccessTokenUri(tokenServiceUri);
    details.setClientId(clientId);
    details.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    details.setGrantType(grantType);
    details.setUsername(username);
    details.setPassword(password);

    return details;
}


@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate cryptoKeycloakRestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) throws Exception {

    // build template with custom SSL TrustStrategy

    TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
    SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
            .build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
            .build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

    AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider authCodeAccessTokenProvider = new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider();
    authCodeAccessTokenProvider.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

    ImplicitAccessTokenProvider implicitAccessTokenProvider = new ImplicitAccessTokenProvider();
    implicitAccessTokenProvider.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

    ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider resourceOwnerTokenProvider = new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider();
    resourceOwnerTokenProvider.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

    ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider clientCredentialsTokenProvider = new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider();

    AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new AccessTokenProviderChain(
            Arrays.<AccessTokenProvider> asList(authCodeAccessTokenProvider, implicitAccessTokenProvider,
                    resourceOwnerTokenProvider, clientCredentialsTokenProvider));

    AccessTokenRequest request = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(cryptoKeycloakResourceDetails(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(request));
    template.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProvider);
    template.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    return template;
}
}



import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperations;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class KeycloakAdminQueryService {

@Autowired
private OAuth2RestOperations cryptoKeycloakRestTemplate;

@Value("${admin-query.admin-base-url}")
private String keycloakAdminQueryBaseUrl;

public KeycloakUserProfile getUserProfile(final String userId) 
        throws UserProfileNotFoundException {

    Map<String,Object> uriVars = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    uriVars.put("userId", userId);

    try {
        ResponseEntity<KeycloakUserProfile> response = cryptoKeycloakRestTemplate.getForEntity(
                keycloakAdminQueryBaseUrl + "/users/{userId}", KeycloakUserProfile.class, uriVars);
        return response.getBody();

    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        if (e.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
            throw new UserProfileNotFoundException("Keycloak could not find user: " + userId, e);
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    } 
}
}



@Data
public class KeycloakUserProfile {

private String id;
private String createdTimestamp;
private String username;
private boolean enabled;
private boolean totp;
private boolean emailVerified;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private List<String> disableableCredentialTypes;
private List<String> requiredActions;
private int notBefore;
private Access access;


@Data
public static class Access {
    private boolean manageGroupMembership;
    private boolean view;
    private boolean mapRoles;
    private boolean impersonate;
    private boolean manage;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check that tommorow

Comment: Yup, the problem was that I didn't add roles using `realm-management` but I created it by myself. Thanks!